# Is it possible join threads from another application in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Any way to check when func_one() is done when it is running itself independently?  No imports to main.py

I can put following code into one file, but I want to have multiple files.

Is there a way to do this or even possible?

Thanks!

## file.py

```py
def func_one():
    # run some stuff
    pass

func_one()
```

## main.py

```py
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=func_one)
thread.start()

thread.join()
```

Comment: What's wrong with `from file import func_one`?

Comment: Nothing, just want it done without it.